# What is the manifest.xml convention for dependencies of launch files?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, manifest.xml, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Often times packages will build libraries and executables that have certain dependencies, and then related launch files that often pull in more dependencies.

Depending on perspective, the launch file deps could be thought of as non-essential. With that perspective, one might seek to minimize dependencies and leave them out of the manifest.

This is not simply an academic question, since, for example, many python scripts call to roslib.load_manifest which will throw an exception if a package is missing even if it's not strictly necessary.

What is considered to be "best practice" in this situation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11710/what-is-the-manifest.xml-convention-for-dependencies-of-launch-files?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should include launch file dependencies in the manifest. In cases where this is undesirable, split the launch files out into a separate package. For example, `openni_launch` has more dependencies than the `openni_camera` driver package.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd leave the dependencies in, personally.  It means 'rosmake my_package' will have the postcondition that all launch files can now be run, at the expense of a few extra entries in the include/import paths.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-02**:
Very true. Unfortunate that aggregation, and fragmentation both itch.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-24**:
A hierarchy of launch file packages may help give it some structure, but ultimately that mess has to be resolved somehow.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-27**:
The problem is that when there are long dependency chains, unnecessary deps along the chain can cause a big dependency mess.